# Copy cart into another cart in order to change the id_cart

Tags: prestashop

I would like to give the cart object a new id, I have the following code:

```
if ($payment->order_result->return->failures->failure == 'field.ordernumber.exists') {
    $dup = $this->context->cart->duplicate();
    $this->context->cart->delete();
    $this->context->cart = new Cart($dup['cart']->id);
}
```

The cart isn’t “replaced”, I tried several things: use the $GLOBALS of global keyword, but nothing really replaces or changes the cart object. What is the best approach?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inspired by the answer of @ethercreation, I changed the following to solve my problem:

**From**

```
$dup = $this->context->cart->duplicate();
$this->context->cart->delete();
$this->context->cart = new Cart($dup['cart']->id);
```

**To**

```
$dup = $this->context->cart->duplicate();
$this->context->cart->delete();
$this->context->cookie->id_cart = $dup['cart']->id;
```

The essential part is `$this->context->cart` cannot be changed. The cart needs to be copied, then the current cart in the cookie should be changed. Therefore the cookie `$this->context->cookie->id_cart` should be changed to the `id_cart` of the newly created cart!

Answer (score 1):

Try with :

```
if ($payment->order_result->return->failures->failure == 'field.ordernumber.exists') {
    $context = Context::getContext();
    $cart_products = $context->cart->getProducts();
    $this->context->cart->delete();    
    $newCart = new Cart();

    if (!$context->cart->id) {
        $guest = new Guest();
        $context->cart->mobile_theme = $guest->mobile_theme;

        $context->cart->add();
        if ($context->cart->id)
            $context->cookie->id_cart = (int)$context->cart->id;
    }

    foreach ($cart_products as $product) {
        Db::getInstance()->insert('cart_product', array(
                    'id_product' =>             (int)$product->id,
                    'id_product_attribute' =>   (int)0,
                    'id_cart' =>                (int)$newCart->id,
                    'quantity' =>               (int)$product->quantity,
                    'date_add' =>               date('Y-m-d H:i:s')
                ));
    }    
}
```

Comment: I see what you're doing. I took inspiration from your answer. The essential part is `$context->cookie->id_cart = (int)$context->cart->id;`.

Comment: Close question please ;)

Comment: For documentation purposes I posted a complete answer to my question. I have to wait until tomorrow before I can accept it.